# Destroy armor stand on adventure mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does anyone know how to destroy armor stand on adventure mode (gamemode 2) ? 
I have searched it on the internet but nothing helps
`CanDestroy` tag doesnt seems to work either

Comment: The problem with `CanDestroy` is that Armorstands are not blocks, but entities. A workaround would be to check if a player has a specific tool in hand, and `/kill` armorstands in his vicinity when he swings it (checked via `stat.useItem` objectives).

Comment: I search on the internet about `stat.useItem` and its shows something about `scoreboard` which probably uses command block. I appreciate your answer but actually im looking for ways to destroy it without command blocks, only item with tags. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score -2):

You cannot break anything on adventure mode.

Comment: Yeah. I was right. You cannot break blocks. Permanent Mining Fatigue 3.

Comment: This is wrong. Items with a `CanDestroy` tag specifically can be used to break specified blocks in adventure mode, it's what the tag is for.

Comment: Boom. The CanDestroy tag doesnt work on entities, armour stands are entities

Comment: And yet your answer clearly states "You cannot break anything on adventure mode." which is just plain wrong. An answer saying "You cannot use `CanDestroy` for armorstands because they are entities" would be factually correct, and yet I'd still downvote it, because it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Sry. @MrLemon you notified me of that.